# Fatal error: Call to a member function close() on a non-object in webroot_path/cakeapp/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/RedisEngine.php on line 216

Tags: php, ubuntu, cakephp

New to php/cakephp,

I have configured in core.php to redirect session data to redis server instead of file, redis is hosted on same server for verification.

```
Cache::config('session', array(
    'engine'    => 'Redis',
    'server'    => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'      => 6379,
    'prefix'    => 'cake_session_',
    'duration'  => '+2 hours',
    'persistent'=> true
));

Configure::write('Session', array('defaults' => 'cache', 'handler' => array('config'    => 'session')));
```

I have verified redis-cli is connecting properly

```
$> redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Also I have installed php-redis on ubuntu box
I have added extention into /etc/php5/conf.d/redis.ini

```
extension=redis.so
```

Now its trying to store cake session data in redis but failing with above error (from apache error.log)

Also following check runs fine

```
$>php -r "if (new Redis() == true){ echo \"\r\n OK \r\n\"; }"
OK
```

Can anyone please help me out what I am missing here.

```
os version : ubuntu 12.04
php verion : 5.3.x
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post, and add the code where you call the `close()` function?

Comment: Hi Darth Gualin its part of cakephp library https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-example/blob/master/php/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/RedisEngine.php#L219

Comment: Logically [this fails](https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-example/blob/master/php/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/RedisEngine.php#L83-L88) thus `$this->_Redis` is never set to any thing. You need to debug/investigate why that might be, e.g. remove the try/catch block and [read the exception that's being thrown](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.0/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/RedisEngine.php#L92).

Answer (score 3):

I have finally resolved this by below steps.

reinstalled php-redis

```
sudo pecl install redis
```

in my case I needed to restart php-fpm to fix the issue

```
service php5-fpm restart
```